# Is there a way to check if a symbol is a valid operator in Python?

Tags: python

isinstance can be used to check if the object which is the first argument is an instance or subclass of classinfo class which is the second argument.

```
a = 1
b = [1]
isinstance(a,list)
isinstance(b,list)
```

Is there a similar way to check if an operator validate in Python? Something like

```
isoperator('=')
isoperator(':=')
isoperator('<-')
```

I am trying to build an online executor for Python very beginner.

When they input like this

[image]

they would get a hint, the operator is not supported rather than current error message.

Comment: Not if you use the syntactic sugar operators (i.e. the symbols +, -, =, etc), but you could use the equivalent function of an operator and have more control https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: How are you expecting to make use of this ability?  A program containing invalid operators isn't going to run at all, it will fail to compile due to a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by wrapping a custom function around python's built in `operator` module. Of note, the operator can be inputted as a string or a lambda – I chose string arbitrarily.

```
import operator
import re
def test_operator(obj = [6], op_in = '> 1'):
  """
  returns true if operator can be performed, else false
  """
  # Use regex to parse the pattern
  pattern_funct = re.compile('[><=]+')
  pattern_num = re.compile('[0-9]+')
  # Access values
  funct = ''.join(pattern_funct.findall(op_in))
  num = float(''.join(pattern_num.findall(op_in)))

  # Lookup the operator function
  ops = {
      ">": operator.gt,
      ">=": operator.ge,
      "<": operator.lt,
      "<=": operator.le,
      "=": operator.eq,
  }   
  op_func = ops[funct]
  # Try to perform
  print(f'Trying `{obj}` with {op_in}:')
  try:
    op_func(obj, num)
    return True
  except  TypeError:
    return False


# Next!
x =[3]
print(test_operator(x,'>= 7 '), '\n' )
# False
print(test_operator(7,'>= 7 '))
# True
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. `test_operator(x,'= 7 ')` gets KeyError ```--------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4bdaa477428f> in <module>
----> 1 test_operator(x,'= 7 ')

<ipython-input-1-55fcce233737> in test_operator(obj, op_in)
     19       "<=": operator.le
     20   }   
---> 21   op_func = ops[funct]
     22   # Try to perform
     23   print(f'Trying `{obj}` with {op_in}:')

KeyError: '='
```

Comment: Let's add that to the keys... `'=':operator.eq,`

Comment: Added, try again.

Comment: my fault. by saying '=', I was meaning assignment, which is actually not a operator.

Comment: Is what you're trying to accomplish executable in another language? _Also, thanks for accepting my answer._

Answer (score -1):

.isalpha() return True if the character is like "hello" else return False then the character is like "+". so:
`"+".isalpha()` return False 
`"hi".isalpha()` retuen True

```
def isOperand(ch):
     return ch.isalpha()
 

def isOperator(ch):
     return True if ch.isalpha==False
```

Comment: This answer doesn't include non-numeric types and other possible strings that are not operators.